Troubleshooting Azure Search: Embedding Data Not Populating in Index with Text Split and Azure Embedding Skill
Thank you for your suggestion @JayashankarGS. I followed your advice and installed the beta version of @azure/search-documents using npm i @azure/search-documents@12.1.0-beta.1. After updating the library, I attempted to use the Text Split Skill and Azure Embedding Skill for our Azure Search Skillsets.
Unfortunately, we are still facing issues. The process runs without errors, but the embedding data is not being populated in the index tab, resulting in the vector field remaining empty. This issue is hindering the functionality of our search capabilities.



I have attached screenshots that illustrate the problem we are encountering. Could you please take a look and suggest what might be going wrong? We are keen on resolving this as soon as possible and would greatly appreciate any further assistance you can provide.

You need to do outputFieldMappings in indexer.
Add below json element in indexer.
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/vector/*",
      "targetFieldName": "Desc_vector" #Target vector field in index.
    }
  ]


After saving the indexer Reset and Run it.

Make sure your index vector field dimensionality is same with the model output dimensionality.
To create the vector field with proper configuration refer this

I tried to do the same, but I get the error "Cannot iterate over non-array '/document/vector'"

I think it depends on the context of the skillset, but I haven't found the good pattern yet
